# How to disable class cache for part of Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing a Rails app for network automation. Part of app consists logic to run operations, part are operations themselves. Operation is simply a ruby class that performs several commands for network device (router, switch etc).

Right now, operation is simply part of Rails app repo. But in order to make development process more agile, I would like to decouple app and operations. I would have 2 repos - one for app and one for operations. App deploy would follow standard procedure, but operation would sync every time something is pushed to master. And what is more important, I don't want to restart app after operations repo update.

So my question is:
How to exclude several classes (or namespaces) from being cashed in production Rails app - I mean every time I call this class it would be reread file from disk. What could be potential dangers of doing so?

Some code example:

```
# Example operation - I would like to add or modify such classes withou 
class FooOperation < BaseOperation
  def perform(host)
    conn = new_connection(host) # method from BaseOperation
    result = conn.execute("foo")
    if result =~ /Error/
      # retry, its known bug in device foo
      conn.execute("foo")
    else
      conn.exit
      return success # method from BaseOperation
    end
  end
end

# somewhere in admin panel I would do so:
o = Operations.create(name: "Foo", class_name: "Foo")
o.id # => 123 # for next example

# Ruby worker which actually runs an operation
class OperationWorker
  def perform(operation_id, host)
    operation = Operation.find(operation_id)
    # here, everytime I load this I want ruby to search for implementation on filesystem, never cache
    klass = operation.class_name.constantize
    class.new(host).perform # 
  end
end
```

Comment: Rails autoloads everything under the app folder. You could override config.autoload_paths and mention the directories you want to autoload.(I assume your workers are under app/workers). As for the disadvantages of doing so - a minor one would be that if they are not auto-loaded then you will have to require the workers before you call the perform method.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have quite a misunderstanding about how ruby code loading and interpretation works!

the fact that rails reloads classes at development time is kind of a "hack" to let you iterate on the code while the server has already loaded, parsed and executed parts of your application.
in order to do so, it has to implement quite some magic to unload your code and reload parts of it on change.

so if you want to have up-to-date code when executing an "operation" you are probably best of by spawning a new process. this will guarantee that your new code is read and parsed properly when executed with a blank state.

another thing you can do is use `load` instead of `require` because it will actually re-read the source on subsequent requests. you have to keep in mind, that subsequent calls to `load` just add to the already existing code in the ruby VM. so you need to make sure that every change is compatible with the already loaded code.
this could be circumvented by some clever `instance_eval` tricks, but i'm not sure that is what you want...